# change home directory only when connecting with FTP

Tags: server, ftp, vsftpd

I'm working on configuring a vsftpd-server for ubuntu-16.04.2-server.

I have set up a working configuration with user restricted access and a restriction on the upper directory, but I still want to change one thing.
Instead of being brought to a user's home directory I want the home directory to be different when connecting with FTP, without changing the actual home directory of the user.

the directory I want to have set as my home directory is a sub-directory of the home directory of a user

Thanks in advance, if any other information would be needed, please ask

Comment: Related: [How to change vsftpd's default directory to / instead of the user's home directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/741164/how-to-change-vsftpds-default-directory-to-instead-of-the-users-home-directo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly can not add comments due to reputation, so my answer can be lacking, but did you try setting "local_root" option to "/home/$USER/ftphome"? So vsftpd.conf would have lines like this:

```
local_root=/home/$USER/fpthome
user_sub_token=$USER
```

That is assuming `/home/$USER` is user home directory.

Comment: Weird, last time I tried this it didn't work, for some reason it works now. thx for the help

Comment: Maybe when you tried it before you had some of the other "chroot_" options off, and changed it while trying to get it to work. http://vsftpd.beasts.org/vsftpd_conf.html is pretty good source to go and look for what you need before asking.