# vsftpd with ubuntu 20.04 ftp home issue

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, ftp, vsftpd

I have install vsftpd on my ubuntu 20.04 server. I have two website on my server

- example.com  (path - /var/www/example.com/public_html)
- demo.example.com (path - /var/www/demo.example.com/public_html)

I have created user **websiteUser** with below command

```
sudo adduser websiteUser
```

Then I gave below command

```
sudo usermod -d /var/www/demo.example.com websiteUser
sudo usermod -d /var/www/example.com websiteUser
sudo chown websiteUser:websiteUser /var/www/demo.example.com/public_html
sudo chown websiteUser:websiteUser /var/www/example.com/public_html
```

Now the issue is when I log in from fileZilla from demo.example.com or example.com it always goes to /var/www/example.com/public_html

How it can happen if log in to demo.example.com then it goes to demo.example.com files and example.com then it goes to example.com files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "Site Manager" of FileZilla. In Advanced Tab set "Default remote directory" for each site. Reference: [wiki.filezilla-project.org/Site_Manager#Advanced_tab](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Site_Manager#Advanced_tab)

That makes FileZilla `cd` change directory after login to the default of `vsftpd`. Like in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/q/741164/26246).